# What is the best way to consume rest using Android 6.0(API LEVEL 23)

Tags: java, android, rest

I am creating a small app to interact with a rest api.  I was using an asynctask and calling a AWS Lambda for the get request.  I was thinking this was not the best way of going about it.  My device is Android 6.0, API level 23.  Are there any other options?  Or is this the best way?  Thanks in advance?

I am using asynctask to call a AWS Lambda. It works fine.

Don't need to share code.

xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using Retrofit or Volley?

https://developer.android.com/training/volley

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I wasn't sure if I could use it with API level 23....Thanks! @nkalra0123